# Space between chapter heading and table in LYX

Tags: spacing, lyx

I'd like to remove the space between the chapter heading and table. This space tend to be much larger than if I just typed (normally) some text after the chapter heading.

How can I do this in LYX? Should I put anything additionally in the preamble?

Comment: To start with, you should provide us with a copy&paste of File>Export>Latex of the minimal file that's showing this.

Comment: At OP: What have you done, except abandoning this question?

Comment: @user115212 Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

You know how to add »ERT« = Evil Red Text in Lyx? Move the cursor to the first line after the chapter heading, before the tabular. Insert ERT: `\vspace{-2\baselineskip}`. Adapt the vertical space to your needs.

Well, this isn't a good solution, obviously. If you have plenty of chapters followed by a tabular, you need a better one. But in this case provide an MWE.

And if your table isn't a tabular, but a table (=float), this solution doesn't work as well, probably...